# Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user() in capabilities.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I had a website which wasn't updated for a long time. Suddenly, few days ago, my website stopped working and found this error line in `error_log` file.

```
[18-Mar-2014 19:16:43 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user() in /home8/****/public_html/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 1289
```

I have tried everything I know and almost every claims found online. What could be the possible reason and solution for this outage?

Comment: Check your WP version / reinstall core WP files.

Comment: See http://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-wp_get_current_user-5

Comment: how do i check my wordpress version without logging in to wordpress admin pls? because, i have no access to website, just files

Comment: @Prakash, look in `wp-includes\version.php`

Answer (score 1):

Solution is include the pluggable file in your plguin file. After include this file easily resolve your problem.
require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-includes/pluggable.php' ); 
$user_info = wp_get_current_user();

Answer (score 0):

As seen at https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user

```
wp_get_current_user() is located in wp-includes/pluggable.php.
```

Do you have this file included?

(sorry if this is an stupid question, I don't know about wordpress)